# Resize JSQMessagesViewController frame on change of container view height

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, jsqmessagesviewcontroller

How to resize JSQMessages ViewController. I want mention one UiView in top of the main view , but when I use JSQMessagesViewController it covered total view size but I need to resize that JSQMessagesViewController.

Actually Im new for iOS objective c and this code developed by another developer I got concussion and I need to put one view in top with height 60

.H File

```
#import "JSQMessages.h"

#import "ModelData.h"
#import "NSUserDefaults+DemoSettings.h"


@class ChatViewController;

@protocol JSQChatViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)didDismissJSQDemoViewController:(ChatViewController *)vc;

@end




@interface ChatViewController : JSQMessagesViewController <UIActionSheetDelegate, JSQMessagesComposerTextViewPasteDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate,UITableViewDataSource,UITableViewDelegate>
{
    BOOL scrollToBottom;
    JSQMessagesAvatarImage *jsqImage;
    NSTimer *reFreshTimer;

}
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<JSQChatViewControllerDelegate> delegateModal;
@property (retain, nonatomic) ModelData *demoData;
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSDictionary * dict;
@property (retain, nonatomic) id conversationId;
- (void)closePressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender;
- (IBAction)titleBtnAction:(id)sender;
```

.M file

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
if (![NSUserDefaults incomingAvatarSetting]) {
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero;
    }

    if (![NSUserDefaults outgoingAvatarSetting]) {
        self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize;
    }
[JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell registerMenuAction:@selector(customAction:)];
    [UIMenuController sharedMenuController].menuItems = @[ [[UIMenuItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Custom Action"
                                                                                      action:@selector(customAction:)] ];


    [JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell registerMenuAction:@selector(delete:)];

    reFreshTimer= [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:10.0
                                                   target:self
                                                 selector:@selector(getChats)
                                                 userInfo:nil
                                                  repeats:YES];

}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

}
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [reFreshTimer invalidate];
    [NSObject cancelPreviousPerformRequestsWithTarget:self selector:@selector(getChats) object: nil];
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    /**
     *  Enable/disable springy bubbles, default is NO.
     *  You must set this from `viewDidAppear:`
     *  Note: this feature is mostly stable, but still experimental
     */
    self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.springinessEnabled = [NSUserDefaults springinessSetting];
}
- (void)receiveMessagePressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{

    self.showTypingIndicator = !self.showTypingIndicator;

    /**
     *  Scroll to actually view the indicator
     */
    [self scrollToBottomAnimated:YES];

    /**
     *  Copy last sent message, this will be the new "received" message
     */
    JSQMessage *copyMessage = [[self.demoData.messages lastObject] copy];

    if (!copyMessage) {
        copyMessage = [JSQMessage messageWithSenderId:kJSQDemoAvatarIdJobs
                                          displayName:kJSQDemoAvatarDisplayNameJobs
                                                 text:@"First received!"];
    }

    /**
     *  Allow typing indicator to show
     */
    dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(1.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        NSMutableArray *userIds = [[self.demoData.users allKeys] mutableCopy];
        [userIds removeObject:self.senderId];
        NSString *randomUserId = userIds[arc4random_uniform((int)[userIds count])];

        JSQMessage *newMessage = nil;
        id<JSQMessageMediaData> newMediaData = nil;
        id newMediaAttachmentCopy = nil;

        if (copyMessage.isMediaMessage) {
            /**
             *  Last message was a media message
             */
            id<JSQMessageMediaData> copyMediaData = copyMessage.media;

            if ([copyMediaData isKindOfClass:[JSQPhotoMediaItem class]]) {
                JSQPhotoMediaItem *photoItemCopy = [((JSQPhotoMediaItem *)copyMediaData) copy];
                photoItemCopy.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = NO;
                newMediaAttachmentCopy = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:photoItemCopy.image.CGImage];

                /**
                 *  Set image to nil to simulate "downloading" the image
                 *  and show the placeholder view
                 */
                photoItemCopy.image = nil;
                newMediaData = photoItemCopy;
            }
            else if ([copyMediaData isKindOfClass:[JSQLocationMediaItem class]]) {
                JSQLocationMediaItem *locationItemCopy = [((JSQLocationMediaItem *)copyMediaData) copy];
                locationItemCopy.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = NO;
                newMediaAttachmentCopy = [locationItemCopy.location copy];

                /**
                 *  Set location to nil to simulate "downloading" the location data
                 */
                locationItemCopy.location = nil;

                newMediaData = locationItemCopy;
            }
            else if ([copyMediaData isKindOfClass:[JSQVideoMediaItem class]]) {
                JSQVideoMediaItem *videoItemCopy = [((JSQVideoMediaItem *)copyMediaData) copy];
                videoItemCopy.appliesMediaViewMaskAsOutgoing = NO;
                newMediaAttachmentCopy = [videoItemCopy.fileURL copy];

                /**
                 *  Reset video item to simulate "downloading" the video
                 */
                videoItemCopy.fileURL = nil;
                videoItemCopy.isReadyToPlay = NO;

                newMediaData = videoItemCopy;
            }
            else {
                NSLog(@"%s error: unrecognized media item", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
            }

            newMessage = [JSQMessage messageWithSenderId:randomUserId
                                             displayName:self.demoData.users[randomUserId]
                                                   media:newMediaData];
        }
        else {
            /**
             *  Last message was a text message
             */
            newMessage = [JSQMessage messageWithSenderId:randomUserId
                                             displayName:self.demoData.users[randomUserId]
                                                    text:copyMessage.text];
        }

        /**
         *  Upon receiving a message, you should:
         *
         *  1. Play sound (optional)
         *  2. Add new id<JSQMessageData> object to your data source
         *  3. Call `finishReceivingMessage`
         */
        [JSQSystemSoundPlayer jsq_playMessageReceivedSound];
        [self.demoData.messages addObject:newMessage];
        [self finishReceivingMessageAnimated:YES];


        if (newMessage.isMediaMessage) {
            /**
             *  Simulate "downloading" media
             */
            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(2.0 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                /**
                 *  Media is "finished downloading", re-display visible cells
                 *
                 *  If media cell is not visible, the next time it is dequeued the view controller will display its new attachment data
                 *
                 *  Reload the specific item, or simply call `reloadData`
                 */

                if ([newMediaData isKindOfClass:[JSQPhotoMediaItem class]]) {
                    ((JSQPhotoMediaItem *)newMediaData).image = newMediaAttachmentCopy;
                    [self.collectionView reloadData];
                }
                else if ([newMediaData isKindOfClass:[JSQLocationMediaItem class]]) {
                    [((JSQLocationMediaItem *)newMediaData)setLocation:newMediaAttachmentCopy withCompletionHandler:^{
                        [self.collectionView reloadData];
                    }];
                }
                else if ([newMediaData isKindOfClass:[JSQVideoMediaItem class]]) {
                    ((JSQVideoMediaItem *)newMediaData).fileURL = newMediaAttachmentCopy;
                    ((JSQVideoMediaItem *)newMediaData).isReadyToPlay = YES;
                    [self.collectionView reloadData];
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"%s error: unrecognized media item", __PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
                }

            });
        }

    });
}

- (void)closePressed:(UIBarButtonItem *)sender
{
    [self.delegateModal didDismissJSQDemoViewController:self];
}

#pragma mark - JSQMessages CollectionView DataSource

- (id<JSQMessageData>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    //NSLog(@"counst of responsed Data %ld,%ld",self.demoData.messages.count-1,indexPath.item);

    if (self.demoData.messages.count-1 >= indexPath.item) {

        return [self.demoData.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
    }else{

        JSQMessage *message = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:@""
                                                          senderDisplayName:@""
                                                                       date:[NSDate date]
                                                                        text:@""];
        return message;

    }
}

- (void)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView didDeleteMessageAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.demoData.messages removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
}

- (id<JSQMessageBubbleImageDataSource>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView messageBubbleImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /**
     *  You may return nil here if you do not want bubbles.
     *  In this case, you should set the background color of your collection view cell's textView.
     *
     *  Otherwise, return your previously created bubble image data objects.
     */
   // if (self.demoData.messages.count-1 >= indexPath.item) {

        JSQMessage *message = [self.demoData.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

        if ([message.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]) {
            return self.demoData.outgoingBubbleImageData;
        }

        return self.demoData.incomingBubbleImageData;
    //}else{
        //JSQMessage *message = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:@"" senderDisplayName:@"" date:[NSDate date] text:@""];

       // return nil;

    //}

}

- (id<JSQMessageAvatarImageDataSource>)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView avatarImageDataForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /**
     *  Return `nil` here if you do not want avatars.
     *  If you do return `nil`, be sure to do the following in `viewDidLoad`:
     *
     *  self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero;
     *  self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize = CGSizeZero;
     *
     *  It is possible to have only outgoing avatars or only incoming avatars, too.
     */

    /**
     *  Return your previously created avatar image data objects.
     *
     *  Note: these the avatars will be sized according to these values:
     *
     *  self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.incomingAvatarViewSize
     *  self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.outgoingAvatarViewSize
     *
     *  Override the defaults in `viewDidLoad`
     */
    //if (self.demoData.messages.count-1 >= indexPath.item) {
    JSQMessage *message = [self.demoData.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    if ([message.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]) {
        if (![NSUserDefaults outgoingAvatarSetting]) {

//            jsqImage = [JSQMessagesAvatarImageFactory avatarImageWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"single_tick"] diameter:10];
//            dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.5 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
//                jsqImage.avatarImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"double_tick"];
//            });

            return nil;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (![NSUserDefaults incomingAvatarSetting]) {
            return nil;
        }
    }


        return [self.demoData.avatars objectForKey:message.senderId];

    //}else return nil;
}

- (NSAttributedString *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView attributedTextForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /**
     *  This logic should be consistent with what you return from `heightForCellTopLabelAtIndexPath:`
     *  The other label text delegate methods should follow a similar pattern.
     *
     *  Show a timestamp for every 3rd message
     */
    //if (self.demoData.messages.count-1 >= indexPath.item) {
    if (indexPath.item % 3 == 0) {
        JSQMessage *message = [self.demoData.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];
        return [[JSQMessagesTimestampFormatter sharedFormatter] attributedTimestampForDate:message.date];
    }
        return nil;
//    }else
//    return nil;
}

- (NSAttributedString *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView attributedTextForMessageBubbleTopLabelAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    //if (self.demoData.messages.count-1 >= indexPath.item) {
    JSQMessage *message = [self.demoData.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    /**
     *  iOS7-style sender name labels
     */
    if ([message.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]) {
        return nil;
    }

    if (indexPath.item - 1 > 0) {
        JSQMessage *previousMessage = [self.demoData.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item - 1];
        if ([[previousMessage senderId] isEqualToString:message.senderId]) {
            return nil;
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Don't specify attributes to use the defaults.
     */
        return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:message.senderDisplayName];

//    }
//    else return [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@""]];
}

- (NSAttributedString *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView attributedTextForCellBottomLabelAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return nil;
}

#pragma mark - UICollectionView DataSource

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [self.demoData.messages count];
}

- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(JSQMessagesCollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    /**
     *  Override point for customizing cells
     */
    JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *cell = (JSQMessagesCollectionViewCell *)[super collectionView:collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:indexPath];



    /**
     *  Configure almost *anything* on the cell
     *
     *  Text colors, label text, label colors, etc.
     *
     *
     *  DO NOT set `cell.textView.font` !
     *  Instead, you need to set `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout.messageBubbleFont` to the font you want in `viewDidLoad`
     *
     *
     *  DO NOT manipulate cell layout information!
     *  Instead, override the properties you want on `self.collectionView.collectionViewLayout` from `viewDidLoad`
     */
   // if (self.demoData.messages.count-1 >= indexPath.item) {
    JSQMessage *msg = [self.demoData.messages objectAtIndex:indexPath.item];

    if (!msg.isMediaMessage) {

        if ([msg.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]) {
            cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        }
        else {
            cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        }

        cell.textView.linkTextAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : cell.textView.textColor,
                                              NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternSolid) };
    }

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:cell.bounds];
    [button setTag:indexPath.row];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(tappedOnMessage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    //[button setTitle:@"testing" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
    [cell.contentView bringSubviewToFront:button];

        return cell;

//    }else {
//        JSQMessage *msg = [[JSQMessage alloc] initWithSenderId:@""
//                                             senderDisplayName:@""
//                                                          date:[NSDate date]
//                                                          text:@""];
//
//        if (!msg.isMediaMessage) {
//
//            if ([msg.senderId isEqualToString:self.senderId]) {
//                cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
//            }
//            else {
//                cell.textView.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
//            }
//
//            cell.textView.linkTextAttributes = @{ NSForegroundColorAttributeName : cell.textView.textColor,
//                                                  NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @(NSUnderlineStyleSingle | NSUnderlinePatternSolid) };
//        }
//
//        return cell;
//
//    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code.

Comment: check now @ChiragKothiya